# How to host jenkins for free

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have recently started using jenkins as a CI server. Is there a free jenkins hosting service?
I made a searched on Google, but unfortunately didn't find anything.

Comment: Back in the days [cloudbees](https://www.cloudbees.com/) offered a free jenkins server with a limited # of builds per day.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider a service like [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/), which is free for opensource projects.  They also offer an [enterprise](https://enterprise.travis-ci.com) service.

There is also [CircleCI](https://circleci.com), also with an [enterprise](https://circleci.com/enterprise/) service.

Comment: just waiting to see other comments :) and i will choose the best one don't worry :)

Comment: [Continuous Integration. CircleCI vs Travis CI vs Jenkins](https://hackernoon.com/continuous-integration-circleci-vs-travis-ci-vs-jenkins-41a1c2bd95f5)

Comment: Good answer, but I think what's missing here is the fact that Jenkins is self-hosted, thus it's NOT free (unless you get hold of servers for free, which is not a realistic expectation).

Comment: Travis CI and Circle CI are cool, but they don't integrate with codeberg.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it locally, especially, it would be easier to run it as a container. Please see this link: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/